# How to get SMC version for 2018 Mac mini

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, mac-mini, power-management

I bumped into a problem, when my USB and USB-C ports stopped working (all except 1) when coming out of sleep mode. I could fix this only by SMC reset (unplugging power for > 15 sec), after that all ports are working again.

I want to check which SMC version my Mac mini has, but I can't see it in System Report/Hardware:

[image]

Where can I check SMC version for this model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Macs with the **Apple T2 Security Chip**, the System Management Controller (SMC) is part of the SoC of the T2 chip and does not report the SMC *version* like the Macs without the T2 chip, which is why you do not see it under Hardware Overview.

You can select **Hardware** > **Controller** to see the *firmware version* of the Apple T2 Security Chip.

Answer (score -3):

You can check the SMC version and other versions in the terminal.

`sudo powermetrics`

Output:

```
Machine model: iMac11,3
SMC version: 2.41f2
EFI version: 429.1.0
OS version: 20D91
Boot arguments: 
Boot time: Sat Jun  5 14:44:10 2021
```

Comment: This command reports "Unknown" for the SMC version on a T2 Mini, for the reasons given in the accepted answer.

Comment: Very kind of you for the hint.